# Expanding List of Special Characters Allowed In Regex

Tags: regex

I found the regex below that I'm using to validate password complexity. How can I modify it to include these characters `-_+=#^~` ?

#### current regex

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}
```

#### conditions

```
Minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character
```

Comment: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-_+=#^~$@$!%*?&])[\w+=#^$@$!%*?&~-]{8,}$`

Comment: @anubhava That works great. Why not post as an answer

Comment: @AntarrByrd don't limit to specific characters... You should allow any language/script: `^(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\{Li})(?=.*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}]).{8,}$`. You're actually making the passwords less secure. If you're doing this client-side I guarantee your clients will get hacked eventually. Do this server-side

Comment: Typo in my above regex corrected in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48119362/3600709) as `^(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}]).‌​{8,}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include those special characters in the character classes:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-_+=#^~$@$!%*?&])[\w+=^$@$!%*?&~-]{8,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/16iCp6/1)

Just remember to keep unescaped hyphen either at start or at the end of the character class and keep `^` in the middle to avoid interpreting it as negation.

Comment: This regex is not working in ASP.NET web forms? I had to use the following `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&-_~])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&-_~]{8,}`

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

I see these types of questions get posted here all the time, especially with the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

The way you're validating passwords is actually **very wrong**. Don't limit the passwords to a specific set of characters. You're making hackers' jobs extremely easy. How many iterations of the characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_+=#^~$@!%*?&` are there? Yes, a lot, but limiting the characters to that set reduces the number of iterations possible. Your character set includes 76 characters.

Now let's do some math. 76 characters, password of length 8 (let's be honest, even though we don't like to admit it, most users use a password that's as short as possible, so 8 characters in your case). That means there are `760,269,225,744,000` possible permutations of those characters.

Great! Now what? Adding one more character to the set (77 characters instead of 76) we now get `848,416,382,352,000` permutations (+`88,147,156,608,000` permutations). One more (78) yields `945,378,254,620,800` (+`96,961,872,268,800` permutations) etc. As you can see, adding one more character to the set increases the number of permutations exponentially.

Whilst adding additional characters to your set may not actually increase password strength (users may still use `e` in the password instead of `è`), it at least gives users the *option* to try to make their passwords stronger.

According to [OWASP (the Open Web Application Security Project)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) - a worldwide not-for-profit organization focused on improving the security of software (from their article on [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)):

> ### Do not limit the character set and set long max lengths for credentials
>
> Some organizations restrict the
>
> 1. types of special characters
> 2. length of credentials accepted by systems because of their inability to prevent SQL Injection, Cross-site scripting,
>      command-injection and other forms of injection attacks. These
>      restrictions, while well-intentioned, facilitate certain simple
>      attacks such as brute force.
>
> Do not allow short or no-length passwords and do not apply character
>   set, or encoding restrictions on the entry or storage of credentials.
>   Continue applying encoding, escaping, masking, outright omission, and
>   other best practices to eliminate injection risks.
>
> A reasonable long password length is 160. Very long password policies
>   can lead to DOS in certain circumstances.

An interesting read: [Think you have a strong password? Hackers crack 16-character passwords in less than an HOUR](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2331984/Think-strong-password-Hackers-crack-16-character-passwords-hour.html).

---

### Code

All that being said, I understand trying to *help* users in the creation of a strong password. For that you can use the following regex (note that not all regex flavours support this, but most languages will support some form of Unicode support, this will need to be adapted for those languages). Also note that this should be run **server-side** only as doing so client-side exposes information about your password requirements in *plain-sight* to any hackers (yes, it's still possible for them to figure it out by creating an account and trying to use easy passwords, but it still means they have to put a little bit of effort into figuring out what is and is not allowed):

```
^(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}]).‌​{8,}$
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?=.*\p{Ll})` Positive lookahead ensuring at least one lowercase letter (in any language/script) exists
- `(?=.*\p{Lu})` Positive lookahead ensuring at least one uppercase letter (in any language/script) exists
- `(?=.*\p{N})` Positive lookahead ensuring at least one number (any any language/script) exists
- `(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}])` Positive lookahead ensuring at least one character that isn't a letter, number or control character (in any language/script) exists
- `.‌​{8,}` Match any character 8 or more times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line